# Difference in RedirectToAction and ActionLink causing .post() not to work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

I have application that redirect user to Index page of some controller from account controller using RedrirectToAction(), after login.

```
RedirectToAction("Index", "MyController");
```

It redirects me to `//MyApp/MyController/`

I also have navigation on MasterPage view, I use ActionLink:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Index", "SomeOtherController")
... (other links)
```

That redirects me to `//MyApp/SomeOtherController`

Problem is in `**/**` character on the end of the first route. I have partialView on master page that onClick calls jQuery .post().

```
function SomeFunction(id) {
    $.post("Controller/Action", { id: id },
        function () {
            ... some code
        });
}
```

But when I call that function after redirect from login it trys to access this route:

```
/MyController/Controller/Action
```

that doesn't extist. If I change my post call to

```
$.post("../Controller/Action",  ...
```

it works fine, but then doesn't work for nav links becouse they don't have `**/**` on the end of route.

What should I do? How to get unique paths from RedirectToAction and ActionLink, with or without `**/**` on the end?

NOTE:

I can use `<a></a>` for navigation on master page and enter path with `**/**` on the end, but I would rather use ActionLink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is that you need MVC to generate your routed URLs for you to pass into your jQuery functions.

1.If your jQuery code is nested within your View, the you can do the following:

```
function SomeFunction(id) {
    $.post('@Url.RouteUrl("Action", "Controller")', { id: id },
        function () {
            ... some code
        });
}
```

2.If your jQuery code is located in an external file (such as myScripts.js), then you will need to somehow pass the MVC generated route to your jQuery function.  Since this is not tied to an element directly, you probably would be best served to set this as a hidden element in your view.

**View**

```
<input type="hidden" id="jsRoute" value="@Url.RouteUrl("Action", "Controller")"/>
```

**JS**

```
function SomeFunction(id) {
    $.post('$("#jsRoute").val()', { id: id },
        function () {
            ... some code
        });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but do you know why there is a difference in forming the url from this two methods?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean - the URL will be formed the same way in both the variations I provided.  However, razor helpers (@Url.RouteUrl, etc) will not function in a .js file, so you have to find a way to pass that in.  If you mean from your two methods above, the issue comes from the fact that being at http://www.mywebsite.com/ and http://www.mywebsite.com/controller/action look very different to the browser and your relative paths get messed up really quick.

Comment: I mean why there is a difference between Action.Link and RedirectToAction. Why they don't create same url?